# Finding a small image in a bigger one

Tags: algorithm, image, image-processing, pattern-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matching a rotated bitmap to a collage image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710799/matching-a-rotated-bitmap-to-a-collage-image)

Given an image with a large dimension (> 1.000 x 1.000). What is a good approach to find a small image (e.g. 50 x 50) in the big one?

The smaller image can be rotated and differ in the size, but only with a 1:1 ratio.

It's not related to any programming language - I'm just interested in pattern recognition.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at my answer here:

[Matching a rotated bitmap to a collage image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710799/matching-a-rotated-bitmap-to-a-collage-image/2710843#2710843)

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to do something with a [log-polar transform](http://www.cis.rit.edu/~cnspci/references/wolberg2000.pdf) as a pre-processing step on both images followed by [cross correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).  The log-polar transform removes scaling and rotation variances, while cross correlation will identify translation.  You might have to center the log-polar transform at various places in the larger image.

Comment: Thanks for an excellent answer. Feels great to have learned something new today!